# 1-step-ahead predictions with dynlm R package

Tags: r, dynamic-regression

I've fit a model with several independent variables, one of which is the lag of the dependent variable, using the dynlm package.

Assuming I have 1-step-ahead forecasts for my independent variables, how do I get 1-step-ahead forecasts for my dependent variables?

Here is an example:

```
library(dynlm)

y<-arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.9)),n=10) #Create AR(1) dependant variable
A<-rnorm(10) #Create independant variables
B<-rnorm(10)
C<-rnorm(10)
y<-y+.5*A+.2*B-.3*C #Add relationship to independant variables 
data=cbind(y,A,B,C)

#Fit linear model
model<-dynlm(y~A+B+C+L(y,1),data=data)

#Forecast
A<-c(A,rnorm(1)) #Assume we already have 1-step forecasts for A,B,C
B<-c(B,rnorm(1))
C<-c(C,rnorm(1))
y=window(y,end=end(y)+c(1,0),extend=TRUE)
newdata<-cbind(y,A,B,C)
predict(model,newdata)
```

And here is an example using the dyn package, which works.

```
library(dyn)

#Fit linear model
model<-dyn$lm(y~A+B+C+lag(y,-1),data=data)

#Forecast
predict(model,newdata)the dyn packages, which works:
```

Comment: Using only `dynlm` package will not provide forecasts for your dependent variables. Providing forecasts for your dependent variables will require a model to explain them and probably additional data. I suggest you to read something about multivariate regression such as "Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis" by Johnson and Wichern. or a course on forecasting: http://www.duke.edu/~rnau/411home.htm

Comment: @deps_stats The dependent variable is what I want to forecast.  I'm assuming that I already have forecasts for my independent variables.  In my example code, y is the dependent variable I am trying to forecast, and A,B,C are the independent variables, which I already have forecasts for. If you run the example code I posted, you will understand the nature of my problem.

Comment: @Zach: Nice Kaggle rating! (I clicked through the link in your mouse-over profile)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Congratulations, you have found a bug. Prediction for `dynlm` with new data is broken if lagged variables are used.  To see why look at the output of

```
predict(model)
predict(model,newdata=data)
```

The results should be the same, but they are not. Without `newdata` argument, the `predict` function basically grabs `model` element from the `dynlm` output. With `newdata` argument `predict` tries to form new model matrix from `newdata`. Since this involves parsing formula supplied to `dynlm` and the formula has function `L`, which is defined only internaly in function `dynlm`, the incorrect model matrix is formed. If you try to debug, you will see, that the lagged dependent variable is not being lagged in the case of `newdata` argument is supplied.

What you can do is to lag the dependent variable and include it in the `newdata`. Here is the code illustrating this approach. I use `set.seed` so it would be easily reproducible.

```
library(dynlm)

set.seed(1)
y<-arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.9)),n=10) #Create AR(1) dependant variable
A<-rnorm(10) #Create independant variables
B<-rnorm(10)
C<-rnorm(10)
y<-y+.5*A+.2*B-.3*C #Add relationship to independant variables 
data=cbind(y,A,B,C)

#Fit linear model
model<-dynlm(y~A+B+C+L(y,1),data=data)
```

Here is the buggy behaviour:

```
> predict(model)
       2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
3.500667 2.411196 2.627915 2.813815 2.468595 1.733852 2.114553 1.423225 1.470738 
> predict(model,newdata=data)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
2.1628335 3.7063579 2.9781417 2.1374301 3.2582376 1.9534558 1.3670995 2.4547626 0.8448223 1.8762437
```

Form the `newdata`

```
#Forecast fix.
A<-c(A,rnorm(1)) #Assume we already have 1-step forecasts for A,B,C
B<-c(B,rnorm(1))
C<-c(C,rnorm(1))

newdata<-ts(cbind(A,B,C),start=start(y),freq=frequency(y))

newdata<-cbind(lag(y,-1),newdata)
colnames(newdata) <- c("y","A","B","C")
```

Compare forecast with model fit:

```
> predict(model)
       2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
3.500667 2.411196 2.627915 2.813815 2.468595 1.733852 2.114553 1.423225 1.470738 
> predict(model,newdata=newdata)
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11 
      NA 3.500667 2.411196 2.627915 2.813815 2.468595 1.733852 2.114553 1.423225 1.470738 1.102367
```

As you can see for historical data the forecast coincides and the last element contains the 1-step ahead forecast.

Comment: How can you handle the case where you have two lags in the same formula?  `lag(y,-1)+lag(y,-2)`?

Comment: Well, then this solution does not work. You need to write your own prediction function.

Comment: Ah, that's what I did in fact :-P

Comment: Did you consider submitting it to dynlm authors? It is a bizarre situation, that you cannot predict using dynlm.

Comment: Hmmm, you're saying they're not going to magically monitor stackoverflow and fix bugs?  I guess that's probably true!

Comment: @HughPerkins can you please share the code for prediction, if we have to use two lags to educate everyone? Thanks!

Comment: Has the bug in `dynlm` been fixed yet?

Answer (score 3):

Following @md-azimul-haque 's request, I dug through my 4 years old source code, and found the following appropriately named function.  Not sure if this is what @md-azimul-haque is looking for?

```
# pass in training data, test data,
# it will step through one by one
# need to give dependent var name, so that it can make this into a timeseries
predictDyn <- function( model, train, test, dependentvarname ) {
    Ntrain <- nrow(train)
    Ntest <- nrow(test)
    # can't rbind ts's apparently, so convert to numeric first
    train[,dependentvarname] <- as.numeric(train[,dependentvarname])
    test[,dependentvarname] <- NA
    testtraindata <- rbind( train, test )
    testtraindata[,dependentvarname] <- ts( as.numeric( testtraindata[,dependentvarname] ) )
    for( i in 1:Ntest ) {
       cat("predicting i",i,"of",Ntest,"\n")
       result <- predict(model,newdata=testtraindata,subset=1:(Ntrain+i-1))
       testtraindata[Ntrain+i,dependentvarname] <- result[Ntrain + i + 1 - start(result)][1]
    }
    testtraindata <- testtraindata[(Ntrain+1):(Ntrain + Ntest),dependentvarname]
    names(testtraindata) <- 1:Ntest
    return( testtraindata )
}
```